# SitecoreCMS: How to create dropdown list field with static values

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I want create dropdown with static set of options. In fact it should select string value.
In Umbraco CMS is Dropdown List out of box, what is the same in Sitecore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Unbound Droplist** under custom types field in  sitecore. this is same as your Umbraco CMS, and assign static value by pipe separated for example country like India|USA|Canada

Below are the screenshot for more clarification
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define your string values somewhere in the Sitecore tree as Sitecore items, e.g. put them in `/sitecore/content/my-field-values` as follow:

```
- sitecore
  - content
    - my-field-values
      - string-value-1
      - other string value
      - and another one
```

and then use **Droplist** field type and set `Source` property to `/sitecore/content/my-field-values`.

Then value of this field will be name of the item, so one of your strings.

E.g. if you select `string-value-1` item as the value of your field, both code samples will return `string-value-1`:

```cs
string value1 = item["Field using droplist field type"];
string value2 = item.Fields["Field using droplist field type"].Value;
```

Comment: This way does not allow to customize option text, it will be content item name. But content item name has symbol restrictions. For example, you cannot put comma to name.

Comment: You're absolutely right. You can always use **Droplink** field type, get selected item by ID and read chosen field from that item.

Comment: @musuk, if you want to customize the name for a droplink field, update the item's `Display Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a *DropLink* field.

The selected value will be the guid of the Sitecore item. There is a straight equivalent - *DropList* this will store the item name rather than the guid.

The *DropLink* will be easier to work with as you can look up the selected value by *id* which will persist, rather than the *name* which could potentially change.

There's some info here on how the Droplink works with the API

[Droplinks](http://ticdevs.com/developers/field-types/droplink-fields/show-droplink)